# Running in Circles instead of a straight line in thirtd person movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

So I just looked at the tutorial from Brackeys explaining third person movement. After typing in the code and trying to understand it I encountered the issue that when I don't move the mouse and just click <kbd>D</kbd> to move right, I run in a circle instead of just to the right.

```cs
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public Transform cam;
    public float speed = 6f;

    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3 (horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;

            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)  `Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.`

Comment: And then you add `cam.eulerAngles.y` .. is your camera following your player? => While you rotate the player you also rotate the camera so your target angle rotates further every frame resulting in a circle movement...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the angles is trying to do, but if you just want regular movement this should be sufficient:

```
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    var moveDir = new Vector3 (horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
    
    if (moveDir.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```